# Coffeescript gives "Uncaught TypeError: makesSelect is not a function" on passed argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

So i have this coffeescript

```
dynamicSelect = (makesSelect) ->
  $(document).on 'change', makesSelect, (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_make_models',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        make_id: $(makesSelect 'option:selected').val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic make select OK!")

  dynamicSelect '#diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_0_make'
```

which gives me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: makesSelect is not a function

It's this line which causes it

```
make_id: $(makesSelect 'option:selected').val()
```

So how should i pass "makesSelect" correctly, in anonymous function it should look like this(tested and works)

```
make_id: $('#diy_attached_vehicles_attributes_0_make option:selected').val()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
make_id: $("#{makesSelect} option:selected").val()
```